# Document clustering using Bag of Words approach

Tags: java, algorithm, nlp, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to cluster the documents I get for Google scholar search using the Bag of words model. I thought of using Java as the language.

The documents should be clustered based on a set of words present in the documents. For example say I have a predefined set of 10 words. I want to rank the Google search results according the presence of the defined key words in them. 
Do I have to use an algorithm like k-means algorithm? And do I need to perform NLP tasks?  Could anyone please tell me the steps to perform this?

Comment: It's called *explorative* because you need to try many things.

Answer (score 0):

NLP is used for preprocessing on text before you do classification on your data.

Preprocessing like

- POS(part of speech), NE(Named Entity) type of feature extraction
- Sentence parsing
- Text tokenization
- Stop words removal

Once you perform preprocessing stuff, your data is ready for classification, clustering process.

Now you can apply k-mean algorithm on that data.

See you can directly apply k-mean in your case if you are not bothering data processing.

Comment: So at which stage does Bag of words model is applied?

Comment: @dave: BOW models applied in training stage of classifier. To train the data based on past historical data

Comment: Can I use a set of words as historical data?

Comment: Yeah, that can be used